# How to set gradient on UIButton in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, gradient

I have a UIButton. I want to set the gradient of button as below.

[image]

I have tried below code but it does not set the color as per screenshot.

```
 func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> Void {
        self.applyGradient(colours: colours, locations: nil)
    }

    func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> Void {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
        gradient.locations = locations
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
```

Comment: What does it do? Also, check [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+uibutton+gradient).

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do it like:

```
extension UIButton
{
    func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor])
    {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Setting the gradient on `UIButton`:

```
self.button.applyGradient(colors: [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor])
```

Comment: Above code works for me , creating extension is good as gradient   can be applied for multiple buttons ,......................If one needs to add corner radius for gradient you need to add just one line code in the above code

Answer (score 2):

You can use this complete extension for all view:

```
// MARK: - Gradient

extension UIView {

    enum axis {
        case vertical, horizontal, custom(angle: CGFloat)
    }

    func setGradientBackgroundColor(colors: [UIColor], axis: axis, cornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil, apply: ((UIView) -> ())? = nil) {
        layer.sublayers?.filter { $0.name == "gradientLayer" }.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        let cgColors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }

        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = cgColors
        gradient.name = "gradientLayer"
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

        switch axis {
            case .horizontal:
                gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
                gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            case .custom(let angle):
                calculatePoints(for: angle, gradient: gradient)
            default:
                break
        }

        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

        guard let cornerRadius = cornerRadius else { return }

        let circularPath = CGMutablePath()

        circularPath.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: cornerRadius, y: 0))
        circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width - cornerRadius, y: 0))
        circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width, y: cornerRadius), control: CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width, y: 0))
        circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height - cornerRadius))
        circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width - cornerRadius, y: self.bounds.height), control: CGPoint.init(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height))
        circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: cornerRadius, y: self.bounds.height))
        circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height - cornerRadius), control: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height))
        circularPath.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: cornerRadius))
        circularPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint.init(x: cornerRadius, y: 0), control: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0))


        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = circularPath
        maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
        maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer

        apply?(self)
    }

    func calculatePoints(for angle: CGFloat, gradient: CAGradientLayer) {

        var ang = (-angle).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
        if ang < 0 { ang = 360 + ang }
        let n: CGFloat = 0.5

        switch ang {
            case 0...45, 315...360:
                let a = CGPoint(x: 0, y: n * tanx(ang) + n)
                let b = CGPoint(x: 1, y: n * tanx(-ang) + n)
                gradient.startPoint = a
                gradient.endPoint = b
            case 45...135:
                let a = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(ang - 90) + n, y: 1)
                let b = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(-ang - 90) + n, y: 0)
                gradient.startPoint = a
                gradient.endPoint = b
            case 135...225:
                let a = CGPoint(x: 1, y: n * tanx(-ang) + n)
                let b = CGPoint(x: 0, y: n * tanx(ang) + n)
                gradient.startPoint = a
                gradient.endPoint = b
            case 225...315:
                let a = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(-ang - 90) + n, y: 0)
                let b = CGPoint(x: n * tanx(ang - 90) + n, y: 1)
                gradient.startPoint = a
                gradient.endPoint = b
            default:
                let a = CGPoint(x: 0, y: n)
                let b = CGPoint(x: 1, y: n)
                gradient.startPoint = a
                gradient.endPoint = b

        }
    }

    private func tanx(_ : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return tan( * CGFloat.pi / 180)
    }

}
```

Using:

```
btn.setGradientBackgroundColor(colors: [.softBlue, .seaBlue], axis: .horizontal, cornerRadius: 5) { view in
            guard let btn = view as? UIButton, let imageView = btn.imageView else { return }
            btn.bringSubviewToFront(imageView) // To display imageview of button
        }
```

Comment: Perfect! I just added this to my button.swift class file, just needed to remove the  btn.  in using the code.   Thank you for your support!

Comment: Thanks look at the edit I have approved the code to support also custom angle

Answer (score -2):

Above code works for me, creating extension is good as gradient   can be applied for multiple buttons

If one needs to add corner radius for gradient you need to add just one line code in the above code

```
extension UIButton
{
    func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor])
    {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```